# How to paste and mark it as code very fast

Tags: discussion, support, code-formatting

I can't paste code without having to scroll up again to mark it as code. Isn't there three ways so that I can paste without going up to the beginning? There's quotes, marking it and isn't there some third like begin with `'''` and end with the same way so that I can paste code quicker?

What should I do if the code I'm pasting is very intended, then it won't look good and manually intending 200 lines of code is not painless.

Comment: CTRL-v select CTRL-K

Comment: Or command-K for Macs.

Comment: "What should I do ... 200 lines of code" - you should stop and read MCVE guidance first.

Comment: Do you ever get that feeling that when you are trying to figure something out and it's a real pain that maybe, just maybe, it's hard because you're doing it wrong?

Comment: **CUT IT OUT**. Seriously. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and *understand* it.

Comment: MCVE this, MCVE that - "200 lines of code? Never. I am a programmer but 200 lines of code? Never."

Comment: 200 lines of code?  In a question?  I just punched a baby.  You made me do it.  Why are you so mean?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could indent by an additional four spaces in your code editor before copying it to the clipboard.  Most code-centric text editors make manipulation of indentation very easy.  In many, it's as simple as pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> between selecting the code and choosing to copy it.

Now, just because this method works equally well on 2000 lines of code as 25 does not mean that pasting hundreds of lines makes a good question.